# How i can add 'N' page of 'N' pages under posts loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop, pages, pagination

I want show number of current page and count of all pages, near my posts paginations. I am talking about this [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current page number by `get_guery_var('paged')`
If it doesn't return value, it is 1'st page.

To get the number of total pages, you need to get the total number of posts and divide by the number of per_page. Or you can simply use `max_num_pages` of $wp_query object.